error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1" also nodes are not showing in EKS cluster dashboard
I have created AWS EKS cluster using terraform. My cluster created successfully but when I check node in compute section inside cluster dashboard then there is no node showing , also when I install kubectl its showing below error,
I try each kubectl version shown in "Set up kubectl and eksctl - Amazon EKS" documentation , always showing below error :
kubectl get nodes
error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"

kubectl version --client
Client Version: v1.28.8-eks-ae9a62a
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3 

I try each version of kubectl shown in documentation but each time showing "invalid apiversion" , also
after successully creation of nodes there is no node in EKS cluster dashboard in AWS EKS .

Check and update the aws cli version to latest. And the run "aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <"cluster-name"> --region <"region">"

You need to update your AWSCLI to the latest version before you configure your kube config to the local Linux system.
This is true if you're setting up a EKS cluster using eksctl and aws cli utilities.
